# changing transition of swipe gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I've set up some swipe gesture recognizers in the storyboard to move between view controllers. There are 4 view controllers, swipe left in 1 to go to 2, swipe left in 2 to go to 3 or swipe right in 2 to go back to one, etc. Everything functions just fine, but when I swipe right in one of the views to go back to the previous one, the view transitions in from right side of the screen instead of from the left. When swiping left to move through the pages it looks fine and completely natural, but when swiping right I'd like to be able to tell it which direction the new view controller should transition in from. I don't see any way to do this with the storyboarding and am not sure how I would do it programatically.

Comment: How are you doing the transitions now? Are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: Yeah, the root view controller is a navigation controller.

Comment: When you swipe right, what code are you calling in the gesture recognizer's action method?

Comment: I don't have any code for this right now, I set everything up in storyboards.

Comment: what kind of segue then are you using that's triggered by the right swipe?

Comment: Push segues, for both left and right swipes. I should note that this is currently on an ipad but will ultimately be a universal app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29332/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-lunadiviner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing transitions using segues, then the right swipe needs to be connected to an unwind segue. You shouldn't use a push to go "backwards" in the sequence of controllers.